# Maven not Building project (Connection Issue)

Tags: java, maven

I am getting this error while trying to do a clean install using Maven:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://xxx/repository/com/fusionone/device/d
evice-parent/3.5.0-BA-CLIENT-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://xxx/repository/com/fusionone/device/device-pare
nt/3.5.0-BA-CLIENT-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://xxx/repository/com/fusionone/devic
e/device-parent/3.5.0-BA-CLIENT-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
get host: Permission denied: connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
get host: Permission denied: connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
get host: Permission denied: connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
get host: Permission denied: connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
get host: Permission denied: connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
get host: Permission denied: connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
get host: Permission denied: connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
get host: Permission denied: connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the tar
get host: Permission denied: connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
May 24, 2012 5:55:56 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.cl
ient.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.xxx.device:device-parent:3.5.0-B
A-CLIENT-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to maestro-project-server (http://xxx): Permission denied: connect
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.xxx.device:device-parent:3.5.0-B
A-CLIENT-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to xxx-xxx-repo (http://xxx): Permission denied: connect
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.xxx.device:device-parent:3.5.0-B
A-CLIENT-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to re-repo (http://xx.xx.x.xxx:xxx/re
pository): Permission denied: connect
```

Comment: At the very end of the stack trace it says "Permission denied". It seems one of your repositories is denying you access. Try removing the repo shown on the stack trace from the POM and try to build again.... even if it won't build, you will know which repo(s) is causing the problem if you get a different error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty obvious: "Permission denied". That's it. Repository (one of them) you're using needs you to authenticate and authorize yourself before acccess. You should stop using this repository if you really don't have access or put your login/password e.g. into your `settings.xml` file like [this](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers) so Maven can introduce you to the server :).

Answer (score 3):

I have the same trouble with maven. I solve this by adding mirrors to maven setting.xml file

HERE are MIRRORS http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mirrors+Repositories

and documentation http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Mirrors

Answer (score 3):

When Maven fetches the dependencies and the parent projects, it throws a `Permission denied: connect` error.
I have found that the issue may be related to a [known bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077696) in JDK 1.7 and Windows 7. The issue have either been with the application not fully supporting IPv6 or with a network/firewall that does not fully support IPv6. The workaround is to set `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in the Java or Maven command line arguments.

Comment: This was the cause of the problem for me! I was connected to an enterprise VPN, maybe there were problems with IPv6 because of that. Thanks for the advice.